# swift ios 8.0 RSA encryption (known publicKey)

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a string with RSA, I already got a publicKey(String type) from the server.
How can I get the secKey without "SecKeyCreateWithData", because this method only supports ios10+ ? But it has to support to ios8.0+.

```
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as CFData, attributes, &error) else {
            print(error.debugDescription)
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        //how can I do here?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`CoreCrypto` and `Security` is seemingly only supported from `iOS 10` onwards (as you've discovered).

You have two options:

1) Generate the RSA components manually, rolling your own implementation (Suggest you avoid this approach).

2) Switch to a modern cross platform crypto library, e.g. libsodium. (Doesn't support RSA, all EC based for asymmetric crypto).

Apple also have `CryptoKit` but that doesn't support <`iOS 13`.

If you add some extra info about your use-case I will happily suggest further options.